# How do I make solid white space in an animated GIF?

Tags: gif, animated-gif

I am made this gif with VSDC. It is a demonstration of the problem I am facing.
The individual images that make the gif has white space. But when I generate the GIF file, the result contains what can be described as faint beige dots in a scratch pattern where there should be solid white. Does anyone know how to make a crisper GIF with solid white space?

[image]

*Full Disclosure:
I have asked this question on several web forums but this is because I regard this as a particularly difficult thing to solve and I have tried a number of ways to solve this by changing the size if the image and a few encorder modes.  I am taking the approach of casting a large net in hopes of finding someone who has faced this issue and solved it.*

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  VSDC is video editing software, and video editing questions are generally off-topic here. Try Video Production Stack Exchange instead.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the solution.  I will post it here for anyone else using VSDC.

1. You have to set the project settings opacy to zero.  You can do that in the Project settings page at the beginning or, what worked for me was to create a blank project and set the Opacy level to zero in the Properties window.  THis creates a project with true transparancy for a background but you have to do more.
2. the PNG files I added to VSCD (Editor -> Add Object....) were pre-edited with "Paint dot net" to set the white space to be transparent (click on the white space and then hit delete)
3. Eventhough the images and the animation both have transparent backgrounds, what worked for me was to take it one step further and make sure the whole project is set to have set with "Video effects -> Transparency -> Bacnground Remover"

Then output the file as a GIF.  If anyone who is here trying these steps has an issue or it fails to work, post your question.  I don't think I missed anything.
[image]